# Is there any country or state where the intellectual author of a homicide has twice or more the penalty than the physical author?

Tags: criminal-law

Discussing about what's worse, being the planner of a homicide or the actual killer, I found a proposal in a country for the planner to have twice the penalty of the killer.

Is there any country or state where such a proposal has been taken forward and applied in law?

Comment: I am not aware of any country which makes it a crime to write about homicide. If you really mean something else, I suggest you clarify what you are really asking.

Comment: Pablo, can you describe what you mean by "physical/intellectual authors". That is not a standard english phrase.

Comment: Going off the OP's Spanish name and [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homicidio), "el autor y la víctima" literally "the author and the victim". I assume he means the person who committed vs. the person who designed or planned.

Comment: Assuming @aidan.plenert.macdonald's interpretation to be correct I haven't heard of a de jure increase (or a solid ratio), but in most US states, conspiracy to commit a crime has the same punishment as the crime itself. With regards to contract murder at least, prosecutors will often give large sentence deductions to have the "triggermen" confess and testify against their employers.

Comment: So in the USA, if I hired a contract killer, I might in practice get double the sentence of the killer or even more, but I think there is no law that states it.